# How to use PHP in JS function?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function onClickF(){
      alert("thx for vote");
     }
```

I want this function to make +1 to a value of the cell in mySQL database. I made a PHP code which do it but i don't know to call it in HTML file.

Comment: Use AJAX to send data to PHP

Comment: Thank you. I will try that.